# How do I retrieve a value from nested divs tags with Perl's HTML::TokeParser?

Tags: html, perl

I'm using the HTML::TokeParser to parse an HTML file and get data within `div` tags. My HTML is as follows:

```
<div class='t_and_h f_t' id='t_f_i'>
  <div class='icon'>
    <img alt="icon" src=""/>
  </div>
  <div class='t'>
    12:31 PM
  </div>
  <div class='h'>
    <a>Residue 4</a>
  </div>
  <div class='f_t'>
    TRUE
  </div>
</div>
```

My code is as follows:

```
while ( $tag = $stream->get_tag('div') ) 
{
    if($tag->[1]{class} eq 't')
    {   
        $time = $stream->get_trimmed_text('</div>');
        print "$time \n";
    }
}
```

But the ouput prints all the fields, i.e

```
12:31PM Residue 4 TRUE
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us complete programs so we know what happened before that bit of code. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`</div>` is the **outer** closing tag. Just leave it away to stay at the current stream position, thus:

```
my $time = $stream->get_trimmed_text; 
# 12:31 PM
```